# Why isn't my app showing up in the Android Market?

Tags: upload, google-play, publish

I uploaded my app this morning, I *THINK I've satisfied all the requirements for uploading. The app shows up as active in the developer console, but I can't find in in the market via the phone or computer internet version of the market.

Now I haven't done much with the permissions yet, but in the console it shows that the app is compatible with 611 devices including my droid x.

Still, I would think it would at least show up.

Is there generally a delay in the publishing? From what I've seen it should be pretty much instant.

It's also not showing up by using the link format market://details?id=.

Otherwise, can you think of anything I could be missing in the app to keep it from showing up like this?

This is my first time publishing, so try to think back to the elementary concepts of publishing lol.

Comment: I think you should give it some time... 
If it's more than a day, then I think something went wrong

Comment: I was hoping it just takes awhile, lol.

Comment: well its been like 10 hours, still nothing.

Comment: Ok I've figured out that the app is on the market, Googling it showed links on a few sites such as androidPit. There were links to the page in the market where the app could be downloaded with no problem. The problem is that I can't find it using the market search on my phone or computer. Even if it were being filtered out for my phone the website version doesn't filter. It's just not showing up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 25 October 2011 - Recently published apps not appearing in Android
>   Market We're aware of reports from some developers that apps recently
>   published don't appear in Android Market. This issue is impacting both
>   app searches and when viewing a developer's app catalog on both mobile
>   devices and the web view of Android Market. We're investigating this
>   issue and are striving to resolve it as soon as possible.

Lol well there's you're problem... That's so my luck. I upload my first app, have no clue what i'm doing and then turns out the market broke, and I was doing stuff right. haha go figure

[image]